# Kubernetes deployment working hours analytics

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

### Background

I have Kubernetes cluster deployed on Google Cloud. This deployment has auto scaling feature activated (by CPU). At any time, I have between 2 to 100 pods.

### Question

Is this possible to measure how many pods running hours I have in a given time range?

For example, in the last 7 days the deployments has 500 working hours.

Is this something possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at Stackdriver logs to events like "create pod" or "delete pod".

Answer (score 2):

You can use Prometheus to monitor K8S cluster. It gives you exact running time of every container and pod in miliseconds. You can easily find setup tutorial.